# Sqli Array issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
 $goal=array();
                //goal
                $sql="";
                //!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM metrics where ini_name = '$ini'");/*table name*/
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                                array_push($goal,$row['metric_desc']);/*column name*/
                                array_push($goal_id,$row['metric_id']);
                }
                                $matrix=array();
                //goal
                $sql="";
```

I am trying to push values from database onto a array , But I get a warning

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Testing\Int\sq2.php on line 195
```

Comment: What is `$goal_id`? You have not defined it as an array in the posted code.

Comment: try initializing goal and goal_id as arrays...something like `$goal = array();`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need 2 arrays. You can (and should) store id's as a keys of resulting array.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $goal[$row['metric_id']] = $row['metric_desc']);
}
```

or, with help of [SafeMysql library](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php), **whole** your code could be changed to

```
$goal = $db->getIndCol('metric_id',"SELECT * FROM metrics where ini_name = ?i",$ini);
```